# retrieve deployed EAR on WIldfly domain

Tags: wildfly, ear, application-server

Is there a way to retrieve an EAR deployed in a Wildfly in domain mode?
If I have only one server-group with two servers (e.g. server-one and server-two) each host has a directory ubnder *domain* called *servers/server-one(two)/data/content* containing all deployed artifacts, but they are encrypted.
Is there a way (maybe from Wildfly Admin Console) to retrieve the original deployed EAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported but will be in the [future](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-380). For what it's worth the contents is not encrypted. The `content` file is just a compressed file.